# Change the icon for one specific file (from the command line)

Tags: icons

In Ubuntu, is it possible to change the icon for a specific file from the command line? I want to create a shortcut with a custom icon, so I'll need a way to change a specific file's icon. (Instead of changing the icon associated with a filetype, I want to change the icon associated with just one specific file.)

Comment: As an example, I might have a script called `run.sh` saved on the desktop. In this case, how could I change the icon for that specific file?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You may create a `.desktop` file pointing to your script and change that icon. Anyway I am not sure, lets wait for a good answer

Comment: @Web-E Why do you think it's impossible? It's possible to do this on Windows (e. g., specific icons for individual files in Dropbox), so why not on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Web-E Specifically, how can you change a .desktop file's icon using the command line?

Comment: First you need to create `.desktop` file. From command line you have to create the lines one by one. `Icon=<ICON_IMG>` this line will change the icon. For existing `.desktop` file you need to replace that line. You can use `sed` utility for replacement.

Comment: Nautilus allows user to choose an icon for an individual file from the context menu Properties dialog box. If someone knows where this information is stored it might give a clue for doing this from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions:

1. You change the icon from the terminal using `gio set` here is the command you will use:

   ```
   gio set -t 'string' FiletoInsertIcon 'metadata::custom-icon' 'file:///home/user/..path to icon/'
   ```

   `gio set` is an update of `gsfv` for anyone who is familiar wih this command.
2. You can create a `.desktop` using the following code:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Name=MyApp
   Exec=/path to file/file.py
   Icon=/path to icon/icon.png
   ```

   and make the desktop entry executable using `chmod +x MyApp.desktop`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `desktop-file-edit` command as below.

```
desktop-file-edit --set-icon=your_icon_path desktop_file_name
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/desktop-file-install.1.html#edit%20options

```
Note:
   You need to set executable permission to the desktop file after running above command.
```